# How to connect USB Modem over command line

Tags: usb, modem, fedora-15, pppd

On Fedora 15, how does one connect a USB Modem (I have a ZTE MF636) over command line?

If I do `ps auwx|grep ppp` then I can see this command:

```
/usr/sbin/pppd nodetach lock nodefaultroute ttyUSB2 noipdefault noauth usepeerdns lcp-echo-failure 0 lcp-echo-interval 0 ipparam /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/PPP/0 plugin /usr/lib64/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pppd-plugin.so
```

But when I try to run that (even as root) it won't connect the device.  Usually I connect from Gnome3's network manager menu.

It just says:

```
Plugin /usr/lib64/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (plugin_init): initializing
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 3 / phase 'serial connection'
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 5 / phase 'establish'
LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 11 / phase 'disconnect'
Connection terminated.
Receive serial link is not 8-bit clean:
Problem: all had bit 7 set to 0
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_phasechange): status 1 / phase 'dead'
Modem hangup
** Message: nm-ppp-plugin: (nm_exit_notify): cleaning up
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try using wvdial. 
May be this guide can help you http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPPP.html 
The following is a tutorial on Zte Mf 180 may it can help you http://christian.amsuess.com/tutorials/zte_mf180/